# Retrieve value from Access table in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an Excel file that exports data into Word.  It includes a cover page and grabs the user name ("First.Last") and changes it to "First Last" but I also need to include the user's professional title.  This information is housed in an Access table.  It has a field called Name and a field called Title.  The Name field match exactly to User with no duplicates.

I have tried about eight different methods I've found online to grab this value from the table.  The table will never happen to be open so I can't use "CurrentDB()".

I just need to be able to reach into the table in a database, grab the "title" value given that the value of the field "Name" is equal to the value of User (user name from the environment - the person using the excel file).

If it helps, I can provide examples of the different chunks of code I've used so far.

User is the username from the environment
tblPickName is the table I am trying to open
Path is the directory and file where the table is located

tblPickName has 2 fields, Name and Title
I need to grab the Title from this table and set it to my variable "Title" as long as Name equals User.  Then I can export the username and title to Word along with the rest of the data.

```
Dim Path As String
Dim User As String
Dim Title As String

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

User = Environ("UserName")
User = Replace(User, ".", " ")
User = StrConv(User, vbProperCase)

Path = "Directory\Name.mdb"

Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(Path)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblPickAnalyst.Title FROM tblPickAnalyst WHERE [Analyst]='" & User & "'")

Title = rs!Title

rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

docWord.Bookmarks("AnalystName").Range.Text = User
docWord.Bookmarks("AnalystTitle").Range.Text = Title
```

Comment: Hi, edit your question with the relevant code you've tried and let us know what the issue / error was with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution.  Thank you to everyone who helped!

```
Dim Path As String
Dim User As String
Dim Title As String

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

User = Environ("UserName")
User = Replace(User, ".", " ")
User = StrConv(User, vbProperCase)

Path = "Directory\FileName"

Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(Path)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblPickAnalyst.Title FROM tblPickAnalyst WHERE [Analyst]='" & User & "'")

Title = rs!Title

rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

docWord.Bookmarks("AnalystName").Range.Text = User
docWord.Bookmarks("AnalystTitle").Range.Text = Title
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Sub JohnTayloristheBest()
Dim conAccess As ADODB.Connection
    Set conAccess = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rdsAccess As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strTitle as String

With conAccess
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source= **insert filepath here** "
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open
End With

With rdsAccess
   .Open "SELECT tblPickName.Title FROM tblPickName WHERE tblPickName.Name = '" & Environ("username") & "';", conAccess
   If Not .EOF And Not IsNull(.fields(0)) Then
        strTitle = .fields(0)
   Else
        Msgbox "Error: No record in the database for " & Environ("username")
   End If
   .Close
End With

conAccess.Close: conAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```

Be sure to select the correct references by doing this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677497(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, this is my first answer ever written on this site (or any other for that matter), so be kind.

Comment: I tried this code but I can't reference Visual Basic objects and procedures or Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures so the ADODB.Connection isn't a recognized object.

Comment: The first instruction on through that link is for VB, not VBA.  Immediately following the VB instructions, you will find VBA instructions.  The references you need to select are:

OLE Automation,
Visual Basic for Applications,
Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library,
Microsoft Office XX.X Object Library,
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Function getTitle(name As String)

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("E:\Temp\Database.mdb")
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Title FROM tblPickName WHERE Name='" & name & "'")
  If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    getTitle = rs!Title
  End If
  rs.Close
  db.Close

End Function
```

Ensure read access on table tblPickName (for Administrator)

Comment: I tried running this code, but I can't seem to get a value out of the recordset. I hard coded User to be exactly the same as a value in the table and then tried to run it and it still comes up blank.  Here is the code:

Comment: I don't know how to add the code down here, so please see the bottom of my original question. I added the code in up there.  Thank you both for responding and helping.  By the way, I have to program this using 2003 Office.

Comment: I can't see your code in your original question. Do you know how to debug? Then you can explore, for example
- if is rs.RecordCount > 0
- which line causes an error
...

Comment: I'm new to posting on places like this, so unfortunately, I don't know how to add code so everyone can see it. I see it in my original question. Anyway, I don't really know how to debug. I just put a msgbox in each area so I know what is happening. I do know that rs.RecordCount is greater than 0, but it is returning null even though [Analyst] equals the variable User which is in the SQL statement. It should just return the associated value [Title] where they are equal, but nothing is being returned.

Comment: 1) Today I can see your code.
2) Office 2003 is fine.
3) Use MsgBox to examine the matter:

A) How many records do you get?
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
 rs.MoveLast
 MsgBox "User=" & User & "rs.RecordCount=" & rs.RecordCount
End If


B) Can you get the Analyst?
"SELECT tblPickAnalyst.Title, tblPickAnalyst.Analyst FROM tblPickAnalyst WHERE [Analyst]='" & User & "'"
MsgBox "Found analyst: " & Analyst

Comment: Ok, I decided to move away from the live data and made a very simple example within My Documents. I am able to pull the title now. I then took this exact code, and put it out on the drive to access the live data and it once again does not pull anything for title. You mentioned adding read access to the table. How do I do that? Maybe that is the issue.  ----  I updated the code in my original question to show how it is currently set up.